# Is it possible to create a particle system which uses collection of objects or merge a collection into 1 object?

Tags: particles, collections

I have a collection which contains 5 leaf objects and 1 carrot object, is it possible to merge it in one object or just use a collection for a particle system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem.

Create new particle system -> Render -> Render As -> Collection